# Логика условий

Tags: логика, php

Доброе время суток. Помогите понять логику.

```
while (!feof($fg)) {
    тело цикла
}
```

Если значение цикла `true`, то тело цикла будет выполнятся.
Файловый дескриптор (допустим в начале файла), а значит `feof()` выдаст `false`.
`!` - отрицание. Получается: отрицаем отрицание - получаем правду? 
Достигнет конца файла- `feof()` выдаст `true`. Отрицаем правду, получаем ложь? Цикл прекращает выполняться?  
Я только знакомлюсь с PHP. Объясните логику, пожалуйста.

Comment: А ведь вы все правильно расписали. Именно так все и происходит.

Comment: Почитайте булеву логику и дискретную математику

Answer (score 4):

Именно так и есть, выполняем пока не наткнемся на конец файла.

Можно оно представить по-русски:

```
пока (не конец файла($fg)) {
    тело цикла
}
```

Пока не конец файла — `feof($fg)` не возвращает `true` — тело цикла выполняется, поскольку условие будет (за счет оператора отрицания) истинным. Как только к началу очередной итерации окажется, что мы в конце файла — получим `while (!true)` = `while (false)`, и цикл выполнять не будем.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему php для Вас является первым языком. Многие так делать не рекомендуют. Хотя я бы не сказал, что начав с языка высокого уровня можно "убить в себе программиста на корню". Хоть для меня первым языком и был ассемблер, вторым - си. Я не считаю, что начни я с php, у меня бы ничего не получилось. Учитесь и радуйтесь жизни, вообщем и прислушивайтесь к знающим. Успехов Вам)